# preloading page javascript - smooth fade out

Tags: javascript, preloading

I have done some youtube tutorial about preloading page it worked but my only problem is the transition from preloading page to the main content **NO smooth** fade out or so what ever....

this is my index page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Loading animation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script>
        window.addEventListener("load", function() {
            var leaving = document.getElementById("leaving");
            document.body.removeChild(leaving);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="leaving" class="loading">
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>   
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and my CSS

```
html {
    background: #abf971;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.loading {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: rgb(53, 53, 53);
    border: 0px solid #ffffff;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
}
ul li {
    list-style: none;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: animate 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
}
@keyframes animate {
    0%, 20%, 40%, 80%, 100% {
        transform: scale(0.01);
    }
    40% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
ul li:nth-child(1) {
    animation-delay: -1.4s;
    background: #e9c70d;
    box-shadow: 0 0 50px #e9c70d;
}
ul li:nth-child(2) {
    animation-delay: -1.2s;
    background: #e9c70d;
    box-shadow: 0 0 50px #e9c70d;
}
ul li:nth-child(3) {
    animation-delay: -1s;
    background: #e9c70d;
    box-shadow: 0 0 50px #e9c70d;
}
ul li:nth-child(4) {
    animation-delay: -0.8s;
    background: #e9c70d;
    box-shadow: 0 0 50px #e9c70d;
}
ul li:nth-child(5) {
    animation-delay: -0.6s;
    background: #e9c70d;
    box-shadow: 0 0 50px #e9c70d;
}
ul li:nth-child(6) {
    animation-delay: -0.4s;
    background: #e9c70d;
    box-shadow: 0 0 50px #e9c70d;
}
ul li:nth-child(7) {
    animation-delay: -0.2s;
    background: #e9c70d;
    box-shadow: 0 0 50px #e9c70d;
}
ul li:nth-child(8) {
    animation-delay: 0s;
    background: #e9c70d;
    box-shadow: 0 0 50px #e9c70d;
}
```

so my question is.. what will i have to add to this

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
        var leaving = document.getElementById("leaving");
        document.body.removeChild(leaving);
    });
</script>
```

to make it fade out smoothly....
im kind of hesitant to put time on it because what if the my connection is so slow that it exceeds the time...

Thanks

Comment: You actually expect us to follow some external link tutorial in order to help you? Provide minimal example. Currently you are missing CSS and HTML in your code. I also see some inconsistency between naming: `getElementById` and ID that is `loadingClass`

Comment: sorry about that... i have edited it

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, it can be done like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script> 
<script>
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
     //# is used to represent id in jQuery
     //"slow" sets the speed of the animation 
     //jQuery works in nearly all browsers as its developers wrote it for 
     //high performance in all browsers
    $('#leaving').fadeOut("slow", function(){
     //callback function to be performed after the animation is complete
  });
});
</script>
```

As Justinas suggested, the proper syntax in complete jQuery would be this:

```
<script>
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#leaving').fadeOut("slow", function(){
     //do something after animation is complete
  });
});
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#leaving').fadeOut("slow", function(){
     //do something after animation is complete
  });
});
</script>
<div id="leaving" style="border: 1px solid black; width: 100px; height: 50px; position: fixed; z-index: 1000;"></div>
```

Comment: So why not `$(window).load(function () {})` too then?

Comment: @Justinas I thought nekomancer would be more familiar with what he/she had already written (making minimal changes to it), but you're right, that is how it should be writtten in jQuery. I edited my answer per your suggestion.

Comment: @hev thanks for the response...
after that fade i want the whole div to be completely gone
because its z-index is on the very top an if i just use clearInterval() the div stays on the top and i can't click anything on the screen

Comment: @nekomancer Check the code snippet I added. Is it what you want?

Comment: @hev1 my bad, got a typo on the script src..
it works now.. thank you :)